# Forward Authentication with X-Forwarded-Ssl-Client-Cert header for authentication server

Tags: traefik, ssl-client-authentication

Passing the TLS client certificate to a backend using traefik.frontend.passTLSClientCert.pem=true works perfectly - but if the client request is passed to an authentication server (entryPoints.http.auth.forward), the client certificate is not sent to the authentication server (at least not in the HTTP headers). Is there a possibility to forward the client certificate to the auth server in order to authenticate clients by their TLS-certificate?